# Why did I gain one reputation point when a question was removed?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

I recently voted down a bad answer and paid one reputation for doing so.
The question was removed from SO some time later.

I presume that when a question is removed, some reputation changes are reversed. Is this correct? I presume this because I gained one point when this happened.

Will the posting user still have a reputation loss or is that also reversed?

What exactly goes on when a question is removed?

Comment: @VMai Yes, that's what I meant, I've edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a post is deleted, all votes on it are undone as if they had not been cast.

The entry in your reputation log is to inform you that your -1 reputation cost from your vote doesn't apply anymore. The author of the answer also regained the 2 reputation points.

Also see: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> - Reputation changes from bounties and votes (both up and down) on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained).

Comment: Does this imply that there is no cost to asking a bad question? A bad question will ultimately just get delete and nobody lost anything and so this is effectively not discouraged.

Comment: @DanJAB: self-deleting downvoted questions count against you and can lead to a post ban. Deleting one or two is fine, but if someone routinely does this they will be blocked from asking more.

Comment: So if I ask a question and it is downvoted, I suffer a reputation loss, but then get my rep back when it is deleted by somebody else?

Comment: @DanJAB: you get your reputation back either way. The exact criteria for the post ban are not public, I don't know how heavy self-deletion weighs vs. deletion by others. Deleted posts cannot be improved either, making it harder to get out of the ban again too.

Comment: Is this fair to users who have gained quite a bit of reputation? Just 15 minutes ago I lost 180 rep to a deleted post. That's quite a hit, and has costed me the review privilege. Does this work both ways? If my answer had been downvoted 18 times, would I have gotten that rep back if the post was deleted?

Comment: @McAdam331 yes, it works both ways; all votes are undone, both up and down. The only exception is for posts that are at least 60 days old and have a score of 3 or more. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that