# Abusing tag edits

Tags: discussion, dupehammer, tag-badges, abuse

Is there some system/control about users adding tags to questions they answered to?

Timelines (I'll use [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to illustrate):

1. Abusive dupehammer:

   - [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) gold badge user adds a [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to a [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) question (completely irrelevant)
   - The user tries to close the question as duplicate.

In that case, there's a safety preventing to close when the same user added the tag. So far so good. I suppose reopening works the same although not tested. So that case is fortunately covered. Now:

2. Original questions edit:

   - Adding a tag where I have gold on a closed as duplicate question allows me to edit the duplicate list (ex: [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) question closed, missing [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), when I add the tag I'm able to add/remove some original questions): OK since python 3.x is a "sub-tag" of python, so it's fine.
   - Adding a completely irrelevant tag just to be able to edit, then delete the tag: that's an abuse that can pass undetected.
3. Getting gold without having 1000 votes on a badge.

   - Say you have 950 points on the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, and 55 points on a non-related [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) question. Editing the question with the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, waiting to get gold on the Java tag.
   - Once the gold badge is achieved, remove the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag on the question: hey! discount gold [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) badge (edit: doesn't seem to be the case: [What is the impact of deleted answers on tag badge progression?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342294/what-is-the-impact-of-deleted-answers-on-tag-badge-progression), so the question is looking more and more moot now...). The only case remaining would be: leave the tag on the question and hope no one will notice.

Were those cases considered, and how do we prevent such abuse? Are there some known abuse cases like those?

Comment: your last point will not occur. According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342299/4826457) answer you can lose tag badge if your score goes below criteria

Comment: I haven't seen any of your examples show up as cases of abuse. In fact, I can't really recall any abuse with that feature. The most disagreement I have seen was between users who thought specific posts were or were not duplicates, which is rather mild compared to actual intended abuse.

Comment: What's with all the abuse fretting lately?  I'm sure this has happened, there is just no point whatsoever in doing anything about it.  First because the abuser stands no chance against, oh, a hundred other SO users that will instantly rollback the edit when they detect it.  And secondly because anybody that would benefit from this already learned that the rep number starts to be representative of reputability and you never want to tick-off the people that can increase it.  Some don't learn this, they burn out and never come back, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Have there ever been (sub-)gold-badge users that behaved this way?

Comment: @HansPassant I just seem to annoy you everytime I post a question here. a hundred SO users often miss an obvious (or less obvious) duplicate and upvote instead of closing. There are also days/hours where the traffic is higher and edits/questions by activity are impossible to follow (on popular targs)

Comment: Hmm, I have no real idea who you are, sorry. People usually respond to [discussion] questions because they disagree, "you are totally right dude" isn't that interesting and easily covered by an upvote.  Pretty sure it is okay to disagree at meta.  Don't worry about annoying me, you didn't.

Comment: (that's because you had the same kind of reaction to another post of mine). That's cool then. yes it's okay to disagree at meta. A question without downvotes isn't a meta question (same for answers)

Comment: *“Are there some known abuse cases like those?”* – I’m curious. If you haven’t encountered this yourself, then what made you bring this topic up?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent those.

Comment: The whole point of having edit or dupe hammer previligies is that one is supposed to be a trusted user. If someone is abusing their previligies in some way, they should have them revoked. Which is a head ache for diamond mods exclusively. If you see it happening, flag for diamond mod attention. This actually speaks in favour of a system that is easy to abuse, because then all the rotten eggs, if such exist, will surface.

Comment: Point three is a cross-site duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110675/tag-badge-triggered-by-retagging-potential-for-abuse

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Stack Exchange as a whole, rather than a specific Stack Exchange site. It should be posted on Stack Exchange Meta.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you’ve already stated yourself, number 1 from your list is not actually an issue. You cannot dupe-hammer a question where you added the tag yourself. So there’s nothing wrong with the system right now and everything is fine.

Number 2 also does not really seem to be an issue for me. If the question is closed, then it’s closed. That’s the important part about it. Modifying the duplicate list will not change that fact. And if a user actually has a good alternative duplicate link to add to the list, I don’t see anything wrong with that user adding that. That may even happen for seemingly unrelated tags. For example, I remember having added C or language-agnostic duplicate targets to Python questions because it made sense to link them for the issue.

Of course there *is* a problem when a user is editing a tag just to do something, and remove it afterwards. You should not add unrelated tags to a question. And if you find yourself removing the tag right afterwards, then that’s a clear sign that you are doing something wrong.

I personally haven’t seen this, so I don’t believe this is an *actual* problem. If you encounter such a situation though, just flag one of the questions with a custom moderator flag and explain what’s going on and the mods will take care of it.

Answer (score 14):

> Getting gold without having 1000 votes on a badge.

Regarding this point. Tag badges are one of the badges that can be removed if you no longer meet the criteria.

So if you add the tag to a few unrelated questions to get the badge, once you remove the tag (or it gets removed by people rightly rolling back your edits) the tag badge will be removed. It won't happen immediately, but it will happen. So there would be a window for abuse to happen, but hopefully it would be narrow.

Comment: that was my main concern, but someone posted a meta link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342294/what-is-the-impact-of-deleted-answers-on-tag-badge-progression and what you say confirms this. Abusing the tag badge would be tedious (because you'd have to do it each time) and hardly discreet, so the risk is very low.

Comment: Not to mention the ensuing mod activities and loss of badger powers, @Jean-FrançoisFabre.

Comment: yes, probably. Not worth the risk